# WinForms ListView SelectedIndices is empty after form is hidden

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

i have a ListView sitting on a form in .NET.

Before the form is hidden the `SelectedIncides` are present and valid:

```
void buttonOK_click()
{
    Assert(listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0);
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

But after the modal form returns:

```
form1.ShowDialog();
Assert(form1.listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0);
```

This 2nd assertion fails.

How do read the `SelectedIndices` of a `ListView` once the form the listview is on is hidden (although not destroyed/disposed/freed)?

Comment: The `SelectedIndices` collection cannot be changed by the fact that the form is closed. I suggest you check for other events that might be fired and is unselecting the items. By `ShowModal` you mean `ShowDialog` - display a modal dialog?

Comment: Another user had problems with selectedindices. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304844/why-do-selectedindices-and-selecteditems-not-work-when-listview-is-instantiated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having a public var on form1 which holds a `List` (or equivalent) of the selected indices? Have form1 set it on the form closing event. Once control is passed back to your original form you could just access that instead?

Comment: i didn't do this exact solution, but an equally kludgey hack to make it work.

Comment: I'd had to solve this exact problem a few months ago, it's a shame neither of us found a better way!

Answer (score 1):

You can try freeware component Better ListView Express or the full fledged [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview). We have resolved the **SelectedIndices** problem here, as well as dozen of other known bugs of regular .NET ListView.

Comment: Or the ObjectListView, or other 3rd party controls.

Comment: Well, the ObjectListView is a .NET ListView wrapper - it thus inherits some of its flaws and its object model is yet quite different (you have to re-learn), although I believe it is an excellent control. Other 3rd party controls may deviate from the original ListView interface as well. But indeed these are possible alternatives with the SelectedIndices problem fixed.